# IIS and multiple domain names

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

I am running into a situation with domain names which has me kind of stumped as I am not quite yet fluent with IIS.

I thought I would be able to use URLRewrite but it did not seem to work with binding within a directory.

**Scenario:**

I have a master web site which acts as several web sites.

**Example:**

User one could create chris.html and it would be placed into:

```
masterwebsite/Chris/Chris.html
```

User two could create mike.html and it would be placed into

```
masterwebsite/Mike/Mike.html
```

I would like to bind multiple domain names to different locations on my master web site.

ie;

- URL: chris.com
- Binded to: masterwebsite/Chris/Chris.html

and

- URL: mike.com
- Binded to: masterwebsite/Mike/Mike.html

As my pattern for url rewrite rule i tried to use ;

- `^chris.com$` redirecting to `Chris/Chris.html`
- `^mike.com$` ,redirecting to `Mike/Mike.html`

Can anyone advise how to properly do this?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test a particular host, you have to use the conditions.
With your example, it would be:

```
<rule name="Chris" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^chris.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://masterwebsite/Chris/Chris.html" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hey this route worked too, but we ended up getting some support and just binded the domain name to a specific location within the web site.  Turns out it wasnt working the first time because we didn't have www. binded :(   Thanks for answering my question though.